# Should there be a badge for highest voted answer other than Populist?

Tags: discussion, badges

One of the populist badge criteria is:

- the accepted answer has a score of 11 or more

Is the underlying logic that someone might accept an answer that actually sucks and that the badge reflects that one's answer is better (by audience recognition) than a worth opponent (accepted answer with respectable number of upvotes)?

I ask because I'm wondering if there is a reason for this badge but not a badge for simply having a non-accepted answer that has the highest votes as well as some minimum number of votes.

Basically a cross between the Great Answer badge and the Populist badge where you get props for your answer being highest voted but not accepted but without regard to the number of votes the accepted answer has.

Final Note:

One dilemma the above mentioned Populist criteria introduces is accepted answer bumping. I have a non-accepted answer with over 23 votes and the accepted answer has 8. If not for my pride (and not having 2 friends), I might simply upvote the accepted answer (and get those 2 non-existent friends to do the same) to get the badge. I know badges are inherently only worth the honor they bestow, so cheating is really just sad, but it seems like some effort is in place for most of them to reduce any too-easy-to-resist gaming opportunities.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with having a badge which is "highest voted answer" is that if someone topples you then you lose the badge.

I think the SO team try to avoid situations where you can lose badges<sup>[citation needed]</sup>

<sub>[citation needed]: I'm sure I read this on an answer a day or two ago but can't remember where!</sub>

Comment: I thought of that scenario as well, but thought it wouldn't be too risky since the Populist badge already has the same risk ( * it is the highest scoring answer on the question ) . Plus I would think the risk would be fairly low if there was also a minimum vote criteria a bit higher than 23 (maybe 50+) since multiple answers may have +50 but usually the first one to get there is unlikely to be surpassed (and if it is, I say both answerers deserve a badge).

Comment: Your statement is incorrect; you don't lose the badge: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58055/229438

Comment: @ProgramFOX - the linked question from your suggestion might be better, as it addresses how *undeserved* (ie no longer qualified) badges are handled : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58053/is-it-possible-to-lose-badges/58055#58055

Comment: Yeah, true, but my comment was more to point out that you don't really lose the badge.

Comment: You can actually lose tag badges if the voting changes or posts get deleted.